# Rails input data not working between pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to made a page that shows you what you introduced in the text box after you pressed the button this is my code. What is wrong? Thanks.

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get '/page' => 'pages#page'
  post '/act/' => 'pages#act'
```

pages_controller.rb

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def page
    @input = params[:field1]
end
  def act
    @input = params[:field1]
redirect_to '/page'
end
end
```

page.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag( {:controller => :pages, :action => 'act' }, :method => "post") do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :field1 %>
  <%= submit_tag "Show text-box contents" %>
<% end %>
<br>
<p> Your input is </p>
<br>
<%= @input %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def act
   render :page
end
```

instead of redirect_to '/page' will work.

but this is **not** the rails way of doing.

Please see Rails guide for better controllers .

You can remove @input = params[:field1]

in routes.rb you can just use

```
resources :pages
```

run `rake routes` in console

You can see all the inbuild routes rails give you.

In your case `def page` should be `def new`

and `def act` should be `def create`

Your page.html.erb should be changed to new.html.erb

```
 <%= form_for @input, url: {action: "create"} do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :field1 %>
    <div><%= submit_tag 'Save' %></div>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks, for the advice. It helped me a lot. have a nice day :)